# How to translate using flask-babel on javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, jinja2, babeljs, flask-babel

I have a python project with jinja templates and flask-babel working good.
My problem are javascript files. I have all the js files inside a folder  called 'static', but after using:

```
var food = gettext('food');
```

Then updating and compiling, the browser returns an error :

```
gettext is not defined
```

I've seen some projects using babel.js or jsil18n but I'm not sure if I really need that. How can I define gettext the same same way I did with my jinja templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If food is a string, then you can use the following syntax provided you have the translation for food in your messages.po file:

```
var food = "{{_('food')}}";
```